# How to use apache's mod_rewrite rewriterule without changing relative paths

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've the following rewrite rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^groups/([^/\.]+)/?$  groupdetail.php?gname=$1 [L,NC]
```

This takes something like www.example.com/groups/groupname and calls www.example/groupdetail.php?gname=groupname.  And it works just fine.

But all the relative links on groupdetail.php use groups/ as the relative path, and I don't want them to.  How do I avoid this?

For example, when a user clicks on a link `<a href="link.php">` on groupdetail.php?gname=groupname, he's taken to www.example/groups/link.php.  I want to take the user to www.example.com/link.php.

Obviously, I want to URL to the user to look like "www.example.com/groups/groupname" so I  don't want to use [R]/redirect.

Answer (score 5):

If like me you had hundreds of relative links in the page, insert a `<base href="">` in the `<head>` with an absolute path (could use relative too).  You'll need to also make the path to .js files in the `<head>` absolute because IE and firefox deal with the base href differently.  I agree it is an annoying issue.

Comment: Note that browsers such as IE9 do not support relative links in base href.

Answer (score 3):

Relative links are resolved by the browser, not the server, so there is nothing you can do with mod_rewrite.

Either use relative links the go up the hierarchy (`../link.php`) or use absolute links.

Comment: so, could somebody please enlighten me, as to how this answer is wrong or bad?

Comment: hop, I agree that your comment does not deserver the -4 it got, I've given you an upvote.

Comment: strange things happen to this answer... now it's suddenly -1 again from only one upvote? ...anyway, maybe i'm wrong, but if so, i'd like to know why!

Comment: a 5 years old answer, and yet this clarifies a lot for me: 'relative links are resolved by the browser'. I suspected so but hasn't seen it written anywhere. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to have absolute links or use `<base>` because you are going to move the page around, you can have the base be generated by php, as following:

```
echo '<base href="http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].str_replace("index.php","",$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'" />';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the rewite rule to do a [force redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) (add the [R] option), then the browser will be using the /groupdetail.php URL and the relative links will work fine.  However, that adds one redirect and makes the URLs less pretty.

```
RewriteRule ^groups/([^/.]+)/?$ groupdetail.php?gname=$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: Kevin, yes that would work but I want to URL to the user to look like "www.example.com/groups/groupname" so I don't want to use [R]/redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the BASE tag, if you don't want to use absolute paths:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Answer (score 0):

Hop's answer is correct. The browser sees **`www.example.com/groups/groupname`** as the address, so considers that **`/groups`** is the current directory. So, any links like **`<a href=link.php>`** are assumed to be in the **`/groups`** folder.

When the user moves his mouse over the link, he'll see **`www.example.com/groups/link.php`** as the link address.

The solution is to use absolute links -- just add a slash before the href:

**`<a href=/link.php>`**

The user will then see **`www.example.com/link.php`** as the url.

That said, it seems from your question that you are using relative links on purpose... do you have a reason not to use absolute links?